# How to generate the numeric value which is not exist in given numeric array?

Tags: c#, random, int

I have this method to generate new numeric value but it takes a long time to complete the function.
How to generate random number in fast approch?

```
 public int GeneratenewID(int[] OptionId)
    {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int SearchId = ran.Next(1, OptionId.Length*2);
        if (!OptionId.Contains(SearchId))
        {
            return SearchId;
        }
        else
        {
          return  GeneratenewID(OptionId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is almost certainly a broken shuffle algorithm.  Google "c# fisher yates shuffle".

Comment: Take a step back and explain **why** you think you need this. This smells like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

Comment: Take the `Random ran = new Random();` out of the function and use a class field for the random instance.  It's taking a long time since the random empty constructor use the system time as a seed, and in your recursive method it going to run a few times before the system time is changed, so it's going to produce the same number over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is going to work for sure so try:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int [] OptionId=new int[]
            {
               0, 1,4,7,3,1,37,9
            };
            Program p = new Program();

          int a= p. GeneratenewID(OptionId);

        }


        public int GeneratenewID(int[] OptionId)
        {
            Random ran = new Random(1);
            int number = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < OptionId.Length ; j++)
            {
               number =  ran.Next(OptionId.Length);
                if (!OptionId.Contains(number)) 
                    break; 
                else 
                    j--;
            }
            return number;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you incrementing `j` in both part of the `for` statement *and* inside the body of the `for`? What benefits does this approach have?

Comment: why for loop ? when it's done by recursive. can you explain.

Comment: this is bad approach  to do. And this is main reason  due to which your code become slow, because each time the method will be called a stack frame(a chunk of memory will allocated to stack for each individual call)  and that may also lead to cause an exception named as stackoverflow when there is no enough space on stack to allocate a frame for your next call..